# The minimum value of $x^{-k} + (a - x)^{-k}$

Tags: inequality, derivatives, optimization

The question I've been struggling with goes:

**11.** Given that $k > 0, a > 0,$ prove by considering the minimum value of the function $x^{-k} + (a - x)^{-k},$ that

$\dfrac{1}{x^{k}} + \dfrac{1}{(a - x)^{k}} \geq \dfrac{2^{k + 1}}{a^{k}}$ when $0 < x < a.$

Deduce from this that, if $x > 0, y > 0,$

$\dfrac{1}{x^{k}} + \dfrac{1}{y^{k}} \geq \dfrac{2^{k + 1}}{(x + y)^{k}}.$

So:

If we let $y = x^{-k} + (a - x)^{-k}$ and differentiate, we get:

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = k\left[(a - x)^{-k - 1} - x^{-k - 1}\right]$

If we then let $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0$ we find that $x = \dfrac{a}{2}$

Substituting this value of $x$ into $y$ gives:

$y = \dfrac{2^{k + 1}}{a^{k}}$

Those, then, are the two halves of the inequality. Where I'm having trouble is "considering the minimum value of the function."

First, I tried finding the second derivative:

$\dfrac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} = k(k + 1)\left[(a - x)^{-k - 2} + x^{-k - 2}\right]$

$x = \dfrac{a}{2} \implies \dfrac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} = 2k(k + 1)\left[\left(\dfrac{a}{2}\right)^{-k - 2}\right]$

I would have thought that this is positive if $a > 0$, which suggests that $\dfrac{a}{2}$ is our minimum. The bad news is that Wolfram|Alpha thinks that the function has no global minimum. The other problem is that I actually found $y$ to be a maximum at $x = \dfrac{a}{2}$ when I tried this approach:

Let $x = \dfrac{a}{4}$

$\begin{array}{lll}
x = \dfrac{a}{4} & \implies & \dfrac{dy}{dx} = k\left[\left(\dfrac{3a}{4}\right)^{-k - 1} - \left(\dfrac{a}{4}\right)^{-k - 1}\right] \\[12pt]
& \implies & x < \dfrac{a}{2},\ a > 0,\ k > 0 \implies \dfrac{dy}{dx} > 0
\end{array}$

Let $x = \dfrac{3a}{4}$

$\begin{array}{lll}
x = \dfrac{3a}{4} & \implies & \dfrac{dy}{dx} = k\left[\left(-\dfrac{a}{4}\right)^{-k - 1} - \left(\dfrac{3a}{4}\right)^{-k - 1}\right] \\[12pt]
& \implies & x > \dfrac{a}{2},\ a > 0,\ k > 0 \implies \dfrac{dy}{dx} < 0
\end{array}$

Again Wolfram|Alpha thinks that the function has no global maximum, either.

So I was wondering if anybody could see why I have this contradiction and also for tips on how best to proceed.

Comment: The function is differentiable on the whole set. The points you need to consider for possible minimum values are the "derivative = 0" and the end points of the intervals for which it is defined.

Comment: Your work shows that there is a minimum at $x=\frac{a}{2}$. As you have shown, the second derivative is positive there, so that the function has a local min. at $x=\frac{a}{2}$, so it is the min. on the interval $(0,a)$.  You have calculated the values of the first derivative at $\frac{a}{4}$ and $\frac{3a}{4}$ correctly, aside from an extra minus sign in front of a/4, but I believe you have the signs reversed.

Answer (score 1):

From Jensen's inequality, $x^{-k} + y^{-k} \ge 2(\frac{x+y}{2})^{-k}$. So let $x+y=a$, and equality occurs only when $x=y$.